# Are there any common concepts in Egypt and Norse mythology / civilization?

Tags: norse, comparative, egyptian

I'm looking for some concepts (could be objects, weapons, creatures, traditions, ...) that are common between both Egypt and Norse mythology/folklore or history/civilization.

Context: I'm working on a prototype for a card game where Gods from Greek, Egypt, Maya or Norse mythology battle each other. There are a lot of distinct Greek, Egypt, Maya and Norse cards in the game. Now I'm trying to add some cards to the game that belong to each possible combination pair of these 4 mythologies. For example, for Greek+Norse I have "The 3 Fates". For Egypt+Maya I have "Death Mask". For Maya+Norse I have "World Tree", etc... But I'm really struggling to find something that works for Egypt+Norse.

Comment: Hey, also, contacme about this game. Sure it as challenge build something alone. Cheers

Comment: I went with "Ouroboros": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ouroboros#Ancient_Egypt
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ouroboros#The_%22world_serpent%22_in_mythology

I already had Apep the chaos serpent in the game as a monster.
Thanks for the input everyone!

Comment: I am thinking about making the "World Tree" card span the 4 Mythologies Greek+Egypt+Maya+Norse though, so I'm searching for another Maya+Norse idea at the moment :-).

Answer (score 6):

[Jörmungandr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J%C3%B6rmungandr) and Apep [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apep)-[2](https://www.ancientegyptonline.co.uk/apep.html)

They Both

- try to/or destroy creation
- where not worshipped but feared.
- Are great(huge) serpents.(although in some stories Apep is portrayed as a crocodile)
- Both are believed to be the reason for earthquakes.
- Both are considered evil

An added plus is that really big serpents will look great in a cardgame!

I found another one in the goddess of

In Norse mythology, [Freyja](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freyja) is a goddess associated with **war, death, love, sex, beauty, fertility, gold, and [seiðr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sei%C3%B0r).**

[Qetesh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qetesh) is a goddess who was adopted during the late Bronze Age from the religion of [Canaan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_Canaanite_religion) into the ancient Egyptian religion during its New Kingdom. She was a **fertility goddess** of **sacred ecstasy** and **sexual pleasure** and became a popular deity.

Answer (score 4):

I would start with the eye of the Horus and the eye of Odin, have you considered this link? Both of them are said to have the sun and moon as their eyes. Both lost the eyes in some moment.

I believe that Loki and Set are not totally alike, but they are the "necessary evil" that comes to cause disruption in the world in both cultures. Lewis Hyde has written in this direction, "Trickster Makes This World" is one of his works and can be a good starting point. Hope it helps.

Comment: What would be the link between the eye of Horus and the eye of Odin? That they're both eyes?

Comment: Both of them are said to have the sun and moon as their eyes. Both lost the eyes in some moment (the moon eye of Horus for example).

Comment: are you able to incorporate that into your answer?